# javascript remove or replace completely HTML tag

Tags: javascript, replace

I try to delete or replace this HTML tag from my code.

```
<li class="li-sortable-background">
```

I have try with replace, but i replace only text and can't replace code characters like <=""> and stuff.
I need help please!

Comment: Can you please have a look at it https://robertnyman.com/roblab/javascript-remove-tags.htm ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) method when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Supposing that you have only one element with this class.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('li-sortable-background')[0].remove()
```

Comment: you do not know if it is the first element of that class

Comment: OP is asking to remove only single element so just supposing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

Using JQuery :

```
$("#div1").remove();
```

Removing elements by class name:

```
$('.className').remove();
```

Using javascript :

```
var child = document.getElementById("divId");
child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, its a string like this and i give it out in a textarea value. I just want to remove LI with class etc.

```
<form name="asd" id="freeld_form" class="sortable ui-sortable" action="" method="get">
<li class="li-sortable-background">
<label for="asd" id="aha"></label>
<input name="asd" id="asd" class="" placeholder="" type="">
<button class="deleteButton"><img src="images/delete-button.svg" title="Load File"></button>
</li>
</form>
```

Comment: Personal suggestion, give it an id (<li class="li-sortable-background" id="toBeRemoved">

then 
    <script>
    document.getElementById("toBeRemoved").remove();
    </script>

If you want to link it with the button add a function in your script

   var removeEl = function(){
        document.getElementById("toBeRemoved").remove()
   }


and in the button onclick add a call to the function 

    <button class="deleteButton"><img src="images/delete-button.svg" title="Load File" onclick="removeEl()"></button>

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".li-sortable-background" ).replaceWith("<h2>your vale</h2>");
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.